# How can i resolve this error in the terminal?

Tags: redhat

## service network restart

bash:service: command not found

## ifconfig

bash:ifconfig: command not found

PS: I'm working on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5

Answer (score 0):

Your path is incorrect.
For `ifconfig` try `/sbin/ifconfig`, for `service` try `/usr/sbin/service`.

Are you doing it as root? In both cases, do show us `echo $PATH` for more tips.